# Outlook slow connectivity - Owa no issue

Tags: exchange, outlook, freeze

For a few weeks, the clients connecting to our Exchange infrastructure using Outlook client (2016) experience some kind of slowness.

The network team checked the load balancer for mapi and did not find anything relevant.
On the Exchange infrastructure, we checked the system performance. The only thing we noticed, is some latency on C drive (up to 2 at average).

Here is the infra configuration (only speaking about mailbox servers) :

- 64 Exchange 2016 CU21 mailbox servers (with latest SU)
- Splitted in 8 DAGs of 8 nodes
  702 databases in total (88 per dag, 44 per node)

Most of the clients are in cached mode but, for some strange reasons, even in cached mode they see some latency. In online mode, some people does not see any slowness and for some it's a few seconds to open a single mail.

Did anyone in here already noticed such issue in your infra?

Comment: Is the troubleshooting guidance helpful to your issue?

Comment: Hello,
Please apologies for my late answer.

In fact we already checked all those stuff. However, the actual lead would be an issue with the AV software used on the workstations.
Indeed, if we shutdown the AV software on some target machines, the situation improve a lot on those ones. 
Also to mention that there is no performance issue on the other services such as OWA, EWS, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog on [How to troubleshoot performance issues in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-troubleshoot-performance-issues-in-outlook-7ac5402d-c4eb-ed6b-9545-b26dde618755) for your reference.